# How to send array and formdata with axios - Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

i am working on a vue / laravel project and i want to send an array and formdata with axios .

this is my code:

```
submit(){
    //The FormData
    const formData = new FormData
    formData.set('images', this.imagesInfo)

    //The Array
    this.product ={
        data: this.data, 
        option: this.option
    }

    //How can i send *this.product* and *formData* ?
    axios.post('/admin/product/add', ****)
}
```

How can i send *this.product* and *formData* with axios?

Comment: Your _"array"_ isn't an array, it's an object. How do you want to send it, as JSON or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? How do you intend on reading it server-side?

Answer (score 3):

In form data, you can't send array directly.

In order to send array in `formdata` you have to run a `loop` and pass values like this:

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

const formData = new FormData();

array.forEach(function(value) {
  formData.append("id[]", value) // you have to add array symbol after the key name
})
```